# How do you use Keras LeakyReLU in Python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I am trying to produce a CNN using Keras, and wrote the following code:

```
batch_size = 64
epochs = 20
num_classes = 5

cnn_model = Sequential()
cnn_model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='linear',
                     input_shape=(380, 380, 1), padding='same'))
cnn_model.add(Activation('relu'))
cnn_model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same'))
cnn_model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='linear', padding='same'))
cnn_model.add(Activation('relu'))
cnn_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), padding='same'))
cnn_model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='linear', padding='same'))
cnn_model.add(Activation('relu'))
cnn_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), padding='same'))
cnn_model.add(Flatten())
cnn_model.add(Dense(128, activation='linear'))
cnn_model.add(Activation('relu'))
cnn_model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

cnn_model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
                  optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(), metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I want to use Keras's **LeakyReLU** activation layer instead of using `Activation('relu')`. However, I tried using `LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)` in place, but this is an activation layer in Keras, and I get an error about using an activation layer and not an activation function.

How can I use **LeakyReLU** in this example?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

All advanced activations in Keras, including `LeakyReLU`, are available as [layers](https://keras.io/layers/advanced-activations/), and not as activations; therefore, you should use it as such:

```
from keras.layers import LeakyReLU

# instead of cnn_model.add(Activation('relu'))
# use
cnn_model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
```

Comment: @TariqS please open a new question with the exact details; link here if necessary

Answer (score 44):

Sometimes you just want a drop-in replacement for a built-in activation layer, and not having to add extra activation layers just for this purpose.

For that, you can use the fact that the `activation` argument can be a callable object.

```
lrelu = lambda x: tf.keras.activations.relu(x, alpha=0.1)
model.add(Conv2D(..., activation=lrelu, ...)
```

Since a `Layer` is also a callable object, you could also simply use

```
model.add(Conv2D(..., activation=tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1), ...)
```

which now works in TF2. This is a better solution as this avoids the need to use a `custom_object` during loading as @ChristophorusReyhan mentionned.

Comment: Very convenient way to avoid having to create separate layers just for leakiness, exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: In tf2.0 I had to modify that a bit: `lrelu = lambda x: tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)(x)`

Comment: to load saved model, use : `keras.models.load_model("/path/to/model.h5", custom_objects = {'<lambda>': lrelu} ) `

Answer (score 1):

you can import the function to make the code cleaner and then use it like any other activation.

if you choose not to define alpha, don't forget to add brackets "LeakyReLU()"

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LeakyReLU

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation=LeakyReLU()))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)))
```