# Unable to load_model due to 'unknown activation_function: LeakyReLU'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, relu

I have constructed, fitted, and saved the following model:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import preprocessing
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
import config
from tensorflow.keras import applications  

model = Sequential()  
model.add(layers.Flatten(input_shape=input_shape.shape[1:]))  
model.add(layers.Dense(100, activation=keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3)))  
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))  
model.add(layers.Dense(50, activation=keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3)))  
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.3)) 
model.add(layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
```

I am using the load_model function for evaluation, and I have not had any trouble up until now, but I am now getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Unknown activation function: LeakyReLU
```

Are there any syntactic changes to the architecture I should make, or is there a deeper issue here? Any advice would be appreciated, as I had already tried setting some custom objects as described here: https://github.com/BBQuercus/deepBlink/issues/107

Edit:
My imports in the file where I am calling load_model are the following:

```
import config
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array, load_img 
from models.create_image_model import make_vgg
import argparse
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
import time
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
```

Comment: According to me, you have imported all modules. But can you try appending one more module `from keras.layers import LeakyReLU` and update `code` for **add model** by `model.add(layers.Dense(100, activation=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3)))` SImilarly update for all **model**.

Comment: @JayPatel Hi, I will try this out and get back to you. Thanks. Just for more information, I construct my model in a separate file from where I am calling load_model.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There seem to be some issues when saving & loading models with such "non-standard" activations, as implied also in the SO thread [keras.load_model() can't recognize Tensorflow's activation functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55364954/keras-load-model-cant-recognize-tensorflows-activation-functions) ; the safest way would seem to be to re-write your model with the LeakyReLU as a layer, and not as an activation:

```
model = Sequential()  
model.add(layers.Flatten(input_shape=input_shape.shape[1:]))  
model.add(layers.Dense(100)) # no activation here
model.add(layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3)) # activation layer here instead 
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))  
model.add(layers.Dense(50)) # no activation here
model.add(layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3))  # activation layer here instead
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.3)) 
model.add(layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
```

This is exactly equivalent to your own model, and more consistent with the design choices of Keras - which, for good or bad, includes [LeakyReLU as a layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48828478/how-do-you-use-keras-leakyrelu-in-python/48828561#48828561), and not as a standard activation function.